# Are there keyboard combinations to restart or shutdown a Windows XP system?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

For example the keyboard combination Alt->F4 closes an opened window. So what are the keyboard combinations for restarting and shuting down a Windows XP system ?

Comment: http://www.aumha.org/win5/a/shutcut.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press power button which is on the cabinet  . :P

or create a .bat file

```
For a shortcut to RESTART Windows XP:
SHUTDOWN -r -t 01

For a shortcut to SHUT DOWN Windows XP:
SHUTDOWN -s -t 01
```

Then call it via 3rd party tools on a set of keyboard actions
look here on how to call an application via Keyboard action :
http://lifehacker.com/5783366/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-anything-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

`Windows button` ,then `ALT+F4` opens the shutdown dialog, then depending on the interface you can choose the underlined letter or scroll the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

looking at this webpage it appears if you press Ctrl+Esc then U, and then Enter on windows XP it will cause the machine. This can be seen [here](http://www.zeigen.com/shortcuts/2007/02/23/shutdown/).

If you have a remote session and want to shutdown the remote machine, if you click the desktop and then press alt + f4. This will display the shutdown dialog on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default there is no such combination.

You can, however, create a shortcut to call the shutdown function and assign hotkey to it.

I believe this would suffice.